# Search the values starting with char provided by user in postgresql function

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a requirement to search for the strings starting with char provided by user. I am using a postgresql function and returning SETOF-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public._A1_loc_search15(in_pattern character varying) 
RETURNS setof character varying
AS
$$
SELECT coord FROM table1 WHERE loc_lb ~* '^in_pattern';
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT public._A1_loc_search15('A');
```

While the select query runs fine if hard coded '^A' is used, with user input it's not working.
Any insight on how to use it correctly would help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're not actually using `in_pattern` as provided by the user, but just the literal string `"in_pattern"`. So you're searching for `/^in_pattern/`.

Comment: :using the suggested pattern does not works too..I am using postgresql 9.x,if this helps..earlier I also used '||^in_pattern||' simialr to a sql expression regexp_like but this doesnt works as well..

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't suggesting a pattern, I was merely suggesting that _you're_ not using one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the actual variable:

```
SELECT coord FROM table1 WHERE loc_lb ~* ('^' || in_pattern);
```

You could also use like (or ilike):

```
SELECT coord FROM table1 WHERE loc_lb like (in_pattern || '%');
```